# Unable to display the timestamp value into Angular Material

Tags: angular, date, angular-material

I could not display the timestamp value into angular8 material table. I am providing my code below:

```html
    <ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created At </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdAt*1000 | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}} </td>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="updated_at">
         <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Updated At </th>
         <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.updatedAt*1000 | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}} </td>
    </ng-container>
```

The input value are like `createdAt: "2019-11-26T10:09:30.477Z" updatedAt: "2019-11-26T10:09:30.477Z"` but as per my code nothing is displaying there. I need to display the actual date and time inside the table.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="created_at">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created At </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.createdAt | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}} </td>
</ng-container>
<ng-container matColumnDef="updated_at">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Updated At </th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.updatedAt | date: 'MM/dd/yyyy'}} </td>
</ng-container>
```

You don't need to add the `* 1000` to the `element.updateAt` as it's not a timestamp but a `isoString`